# How to notify web application from a ClickOnce application when it starts

Tags: .net, winforms, web-applications, clickonce, communication

On one side, I have a .NET Desktop application, deployed with ClickOnce in virtual directory in IIS Express 7.5. On the other side, I have a Java EE web application, with a link to the publication URL of the desktop app. When the web user clicks this link, the Desktop app is automatically downloaded/updated and launched.

I'd like the desktop app to notify the web application once it's running. And I'd like to do this with both Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox browsers...

Do you know how could I do that?

Comment: In addition, just in case, I've been reading some technical info about namespace System.Deployment.Application in MSDN, and have seen an event 'InPlaceHostingManager.DownloadApplicationCompleted'... But I'm still stuck figure out how to notify IE/FF browser when this event happens...

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned this in another post, Microsoft has a ClickOnce [InPlaceHostingManager Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx) and the code samples worked fine for me.  It is good for tayloring manual installations and updates.

dgp

Comment: Thanks @dpg +1, good link, I think it'll be usefull for me. But the web app I have to notify is J2EE. What I'm really stuck on is how to notify that web app from the .NET Winform app...

Comment: I've been thinking about sharing a cookie between the apps. I'm looking for information about that now...